# 6.01 Opening Error Windows 10: (0xc00000022)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

The complete error message is:

> The application was unable to start correctly
>   (0xc00000022). Click OK to close application

Previous versions of Tor have worked perfectly, and there have been no changes to my system.  Please Help!

Comment: Check your Anti-Virus logs, uninstall Trusteer Rapport if it's on your computer, check your Windows Event Logs. Let us know if theres anything about firefox.exe or Tor Browser in the aforementioned logs. We can only speculate without further information.